# How to list all iSCSI connections on a server?

Tags: batch-file, iscsi

I am trying to list all iSCSI connections on my network. I saw a great way of doing this one  "Hey, Scripting Guy!" through powershell 3.0, but I need an alternate way. Does anyone have any ideas of how to get an iSCSI connection through commandline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

psexec @listOfServers.txt -u DOMAIN\user iscsicli ListTargets